# Looking for a word or phrase that means a type of substance plus how much of it

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In a recipe we might have: "Flour: 2 cups".

In chemistry, the analog is like: "2 drops of water".

Similarly, In medicine: "Aspirin: 80mg".

The name of the substance by itself has names like "ingredient", "reagent", "medication". Likewise, the amount can be called "amount" or "dosage".

But I need a name for both together and haven't been able to think of what to call it. Is there a word or phrase that means that?

Perhaps it would be used like this: The third ???? in the recipe is "2 cups flour"

EDIT:
A word that is really close is the medical usage of "prescription". For example, "The prescription was for 80mg of aspirin."

Comment: You can use 'item'. "The third **item** in the recipe is "2 cups flour.""

Comment: But item doesn't have the meaning of "type of something + amount of it"

Comment: BruceDLong, what makes you think there should be one such word?

Comment: How can one word be customize to produce several different items with their unique measures? In Computer Science, "object" can be used because every instances of an object has its own properties (e.g. name of item and measure).

Comment: That is why I asked for a word OR phrase. It is so common that a substance is specified with an amount that I think there may be such a word. But I don't know for sure, of course.

Comment: Unless your single word is “specification” or “amount of” or “quantity of” - and yes I did notice that “… of” mens they're not single words - what makes you think you could ever need that, please?

For at least hundreds of years there have been culinary, alchemical and biological recipes, formulae or what have you using both quantities and qualities… as, for instance, "Aspirin: 80mg”.

Now, you’d like not only to re-invent the wheel, and in a way most people would think impossible?

Comment: Try "assortment" e.g. "Assortment of 12 Culinary Herb Seeds".

Comment: may i ask what are we making!?

Comment: I think in your example 'dosage' can also cover the substance. It's the amount of medicine to be given. The dosage is 3 aspirins two times daily.

Comment: I'm not sure you can't use "ingredient" in a looser sense.   "The third ingredient in the recipe is 2 cups flour".  Even if that is not technically correct, nobody would see that and go "Whoa! that just doesn't sound right."  I'd call it within the bounds of literary license.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Perhaps [formula](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/formula?s=ts)?

From Dictionary.com:

```
5a) a prescription for making up a medicine, baby's food, etc
 b) substance prepared according to such a prescription
```

Comment: This is really very close. Probably close enough for my purpose. I suppose technically, what I want is a "term" in a formula. In a term like "3X" the three is the amount and the X is the type. But term doesn't sound right for some reason. I'm going with formula.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you're not going to find a word that encompasses both the type of item and the quantity (or mass or value). However, there are specialized words that refers to a multiplicity of a specific type of animal, for instance:

- A pride of lions
- A zeal (or dazzle) of zebras
- A sleuth of bears

Getting closer to your question, though, you're going to be hard-pressed to find the words you are looking for, since they probably don't even exist. The only word I can think of that comes close to what you are looking for is *clove*, since it almost always refers specifically to a clove of garlic, where you have a specific item (garlic) and a specific amount (clove). But even there, it would sound odd to just ask for a clove; you'd almost always say a "garlic clove."

Comment: "A clove" does have a meaning in recipes, but it has nothing to do with garlic.

Comment: I looked it up on dictionary.com and see that TimLymington is correct, though, when you go to the grocery store, you can ask for a clove of garlic and get a ready response, but you would get some stares if you asked the produce person for a clove of blueberries, strawberries, or honeydoo.

Comment: It wasn't your suggestion for a word or phrase, but you DID use the phrase "multiplicity of a specific type". Technically that would work but I'm hoping for something more sonorous.

Comment: Well, if you get James Earl Jones to say it, it will be more sonorous.

Comment: You can sort of do it with a generic term for the type or function of the item, but it is one item at a time.  For example: "the sweetener in the recipe is 2 tsp sugar".

Answer (score 1):

Among "Flour: 2 cups," "2 drops of water," and "Aspirin: 80mg," one word that expresses the same idea for all of them is [**measure**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/measure):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1 a** (1) : an adequate or due portion
> **d** (1) : a measured quantity

Hence, you would dispense a **measure** of flour, water, or aspirin.